# Temperature as a period of imaginary time in black hole thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes

When evaluating the action in black hole thermodynamics, we always make the transformation to an imaginary time via $t \to i \tau$ which leads to us having an Euclidean-signature action. To perform the integral over the imaginary time, everyone takes the imaginary time to be periodic with period $\beta = 1/T$, where $T$ is the temperature.

I understand that this has roots in path integral formulation and quantum gravity and all that. However, could we explain why we impose the period $\beta$ within the framework of classical BH thermodynamics, without the use of the path integral formulation? I know that it is related to the conical singularity but I honestly do not understand this well.

Comment: The request "without the use of the path integral formulation" might make this difficult to answer, because (as far as I understand) the path integral formulation *is* the context in which the imaginary-time trick is meaningful. Related: [Why is Euclidean Time Periodic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/558753). Are you mainly asking for a better understanding of why avoiding a conical singularity requires choosing a specific period for the imaginary time coordinate? That's independent of thermodynamics and so can be answered without using the path integral formulation.

Comment: Hi @ChiralAnomaly, well I understand how removing a conical singularity by making a timelike coordinate periodic works, I am particularly interested in why this turns out to be the time in the case of (black hole) thermodynamics. I am hoping to understand it without referring to the path integral yes :\