# It the thermal expectation value of an operator time-dependent?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function, trace

In Euclidean time $\tau$, $\langle \hat O(\tau )\rangle= Z^{-1}\mbox{Tr}(e^{-\beta \hat H} \hat O(\tau ))=Z^{-1}\mbox{Tr}(e^{-\beta \hat H} e^{\hat H\tau}\hat O(0 )e^{-\hat H\tau})=Z^{-1}\mbox{Tr}(e^{-\beta \hat H} e^{\hat H\tau}e^{-\hat H\tau}\hat O(0 ))=Z^{-1}\mbox{Tr}(e^{-\beta \hat H} \hat O(0 ))=\langle \hat O(0)\rangle$

Where $Z=\mbox{Tr}\ e^{-\beta H}$ is the thermal partition function.

This doesn't agree with what I thought the answer should be (and in particular it doesn't agree with discrete spectrum). I used the fact that operators within the trace commute. Did I go wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the order of operators under trace this way. Only cyclic permutation of operators is allowed:
\begin{equation}
   \mathrm{Tr}\,{ABCD} = \mathrm{Tr}\,{DABC} = \mathrm{Tr}\,{CDAB} = \mathrm{Tr}\,{BCDA},
\end{equation}
and analogously for larger number of operators. For that, see the **Cyclic property** section [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)). On the contrary, the equality that you used does not hold unless $C$ and $D$ commute:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Tr}\,{ABCD} \ne \mathrm{Tr}\,{ABDC}.
\end{equation}
Regarding your derivation, $\hat{O}(0)$ does not commute with $e^{-\hat{H}\tau}$ in general.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I am still having some issues. For example Tr(CDAB) would be the permutation (13)(24) which isn't cyclic. I ran a simulation and they do commute that way. Meanwhile Tr(ABDC) is (34) which is cyclic (according to wikipedia), but indeed it does not commute. So it must be the stricter definition of cyclic, which is that it uses the full n-cycle for the $S_n$ element, but it still doesn't explain why  (13)(24) isn't cyclic but it still commutes. Maybe I am computing my cycles wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see, there is a misconception in the usage of term "cyclic permutation". I agree that $(34)$ is a cyclic permutation according to the combinatorial definition, whereas it doesn't preserve trace, and it shouldn't. What is meant is called [circular shift permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift), which is written in cycle notation as $(1234)$, and all its powers: $(1234)^2 = (13)(24)$, $(1234)^3 = (1432)$. Also, on [Wolfram website](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicPermutation.html), they call such permutations cyclic.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the mistake on Wikipedia. Now it makes sense. Thank you again for the assistance.

Comment: Why can't we use a (1234) permutation to bring $e^{-\tau H} $ to the front and then use the fact that it commutes with $e^{-\beta H}$ to cancel with $e^{-\tau H}$?

$\langle \hat O(\tau )\rangle = Z^{-1}(e^{-\beta H} e^{\tau H}\hat O(0)e^{-\tau H})=Z^{-1}(e^{-\tau H}e^{-\beta H} e^{\tau H}\hat O(0))=Z^{-1}(e^{-\beta H} e^{-\tau H}e^{\tau H}\hat O(0))=Z^{-1}(e^{-\beta H} \hat O(0))$

Comment: I think it proves that your original claim that $O(\tau)$ doesn't depend on $\tau$ is true. Sorry for didn't noticing it first time, I was distracted by that trace property. I see that my original answer should be completely rewritten: it addresses only a minor mistake in your derivation but doesn't answer the question about $O(\tau)$.